# How can I access Unique ID in apache?

Tags: php, macos, apache, audit

How can I access the unique_id that apache tracks for each request?  I'd like to track it in any php scripts it calls as well as have it logged for each request.

I remove comment on the following line from `http.conf` file:

```
LoadModule unique_id_module libexec/apache2/mod_unique_id.so
```

and I am trying to reference the ID in this simple php script:

```
<?php

print("Hello world\n");
print($_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID']);
?>
```

Yet this script returns only `Hello World`.

Is this possible to do?  I'm running macos if that makes any difference.

A var_dump of $_SERVER is as follows:

```
array(29) { ["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(9) "localhost" 
["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(10) "keep-alive" 
["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]=> string(9) "max-age=0" 
["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(74) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(120) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(17) "gzip,deflate,sdch" 
["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.8" 
["HTTP_COOKIE"]=> string(11) "undefined=0" 
["PATH"]=> string(186) "/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin" 
["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(67) "Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.26 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8y" 
    ["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(9) "localhost" 
    ["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(3) "::1" 
    ["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" 
    ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(3) "::1" 
    ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(28) "/Library/WebServer/Documents" 
    ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=> string(15) "you@example.com" 
    ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(35) "/Library/WebServer/Documents/id.php" 
    ["REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(5) "49669" 
    ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" 
    ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" 
    ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET" 
    ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(7) "/id.php" 
    ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(7) "/id.php" 
    ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(7) "/id.php" 
    ["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1397681759) 
    ["argv"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["argc"]=> int(0) }
```

Another problem I am having in the same area may point to the problem at hand:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127801/where-are-the-apache-config-files-stored?noredirect=1#comment149749_127801

Comment: Did you re-start apache?

Comment: Yes, it has been restarted.  I did a `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart`

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER) to see what you have to work with

Comment: var_dump of $_SERVER added

Comment: Apparently the module isn't loaded.  Can you confirm that `libexec/apache2/mod_unique_id.so` exists?  What do the apache logs say right after you restart it?

Comment: The module is there:  `$ ls -l /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_unique_id.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  19296 Jan 16 23:49 /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_unique_id.so`.  Nothing is getting written to a log when I restart it.  Currently it looks as if access requests and errors are being logged as the access_log and error_log are all that are being written to...

Comment: Check does module is listed when you execute `apachectl -M | sort`

Comment: @mikikg - the module is listed with the above command

Comment: @WildBill hmm, need to work then! No idea what is wrong in your case :(

Comment: And [apache_getenv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php)('UNIQUE_ID') doesn't work either I take it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a `/usr/sbin/httpd -k stop` and then a `/usr/sbin/httpd -k start` to get the config to take.  Unsure why `sudo apachectl restart` LOOKED like it was restarting, but it wasn't....

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in bounty comments, on OS X there are some issues regarding configuration files.
For example, on OS X 10.7 I'm successfully enabled mod_unique_id in httpd.conf and if I make restart via Preference Pane - Web Sharing everything works as expected, but if I do restart via apachectl command some strange problems aries.

In OS X 10.9 there is no Web Sharing in Preference Pane so my advice is to stick to PHP's unique ID generator, for example those functions may help:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php and 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

Comment: I'm not following how PHP's unique ID generator can be used in place of the apache Unique_ID.  Unique_ID from apache is based on the WEB REQUEST.  Generating a unique ID once inside the php will give me a unique ID, but it does not link that script back to the originating call from Apache.

Comment: I'm running 10.8, but there is no web sharing in the preference pane there as well...

Comment: Apache's mod_unique_id will generate unique ID on every call to script. You can get same behavior using those PHP functions, simple somewhere in top of your script generate unique ID and use it on same way as you would use it via _SERVER["UNIQUE_ID"].

Comment: I understand the PHP unique ID will be a unique ID, but I want the unique ID that is associated with Apache.  The Apache unique_ID is associated with the apache, request, correct?  Thus if my understanding is correct a single HTTP request that Apache fields will generate a Unqiue_ID.  If that request calls multiple php scripts, all of those calls (form the same request) will reference the same Apache Unique_ID.  Thus a PHP unique ID would not be what I am looking for - the ID of the apache call that prompted the php script(s).

Comment: You are right. Apache's ID generator is related to singe HTTP request. My solution practically can do same thing if you generate that ID only once somewhere in top/start of your script. Just need to be sure that function which generate it is called only once per request and prevent calling it in some other included files. It is not perfect/easy as with mod_unique_id but with little care of execution flow in script can do the job.

Comment: Yes but how could I use this solution if multiple php scripts were called during the same request?  IE: user makes a single request that prompts multiple php scripts.  In that case I want the Apache Unique_ID for those php calls, not a unique ID for each php script.

Comment: I don't understand you requirements, how one HTTP request can open several php script? Does you mean on included files within single script or something like frames or AJAX requests? In case of frames/AJAX you will get unique ID anyway because for web server that is different HTTP request!

Comment: That's true, it would be a unique ID each time, but if I am logging everythign in apache, and Apche ID 1234567 was used to call a script, I can backtrack exactly what apache call prompted that php script.  If the ID is within the php script only, I cannot link it back to the instance of apache that called the script.

Comment: I'm trying to build an audit trail between apache and php for every request.  Thus if I only have a unique id created within php, how can I use that to decipher how apache called that script?

Comment: Oh I see, all this is related to logging. I first think that is related to some other stuff. Ok, let me try some other solution, will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

In my fresh install of OS X 10.9.2, I have enabled unique_id_module and php5_module in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, restart web server with `sudo apachectl restart` and it works correct.

I get unique_id_module listed when executing `apachectl -M | sort` and also got `_SERVER["UNIQUE_ID"]` in PHP script.

With script like:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER["UNIQUE_ID"];
?>
```

I have output like this:

```
U08ZosCoAAMAAC9CATgAAAAA
```

Comment: I've done just that with no dice.  Did you see the issue in my other stack question (RE: apache config files)?  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127801/where-are-the-apache-config-files-stored?noredirect=1#comment149749_127801

Comment: I have done this on another OS X 10.9.2 machine and again work correct

Answer (score 0):

Create a phpinfo.php script with following text inside:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

After that - open it in the browser and see if unique_id_module is listed as 'loaded'.

Answer (score 0):

As it said in [module documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_unique_id.html):

> The environment variable UNIQUE_ID is set to the identifier for each request

Try to use `getenv('UNIQUE_ID')` instead of `$_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID']`, its not the same

Answer (score 0):

```sh
a2enmod unique_id
```

That worked for me after restarting Apache.  I was getting a hyphen when using %{UNIQUE_ID}e with a custom LogFormat.